# Backbone.js : _.template() function structure

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am looking at javascript code of an app built by using Backbone.js

there I find a function

```
render: function () {
        var that = this,
            template = _.template($(that.templateId).html(), that.model.attributes);

    }
```

and Here **templateId:"#abc"**

I am just trying to understand about the structure of _.template() function

Can anyone please help me out in understanding and how it is taking **that.model.attributes** as input

please pardon me if you need some more information.

Answer (score 2):

As the manual said:

> **template**
>
> _.template(templateString, [data], [settings])
>
> Compiles JavaScript templates into functions that can be evaluated for
> rendering.
>
> ...you can pass the data object as the second parameter to template in order to render immediately instead of returning a template function.

source: http://underscorejs.org/#template

So basically, `_.template()` take the html (template script) of the DOM element with id=`abc` defined somewhere in your DOM. Compile the data passed `that.model.attributes` and return the DOM part rendered and ready to be used.

In case you're not passing the second argument `data` you'll get a template function to be used then, i.e:

```
var rendered = template({whatever: that.model.attributes});
```

`that.model.attributes` so `this.model.attributes` so (pseudo) `thisview.model.attributes` refers to model binded to this view.

**Anyway, I suggest you to read**

- http://backbonejs.org/
- http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html
- http://underscorejs.org/
- http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html

Comment: you said that it returns a function but I can see it return a variable name template like                                              template = _.template($(that.templateId).html(), that.model.attributes);                                                    $("def").html(template);

Comment: I suppose the author has a more concrete idea than mine and yours. He wrote : `Compiles JavaScript templates into functions that can be evaluated for rendering.` So I suppose `template = _.template($(that.templateId).html()...` return a function that can be used then as `template()` for rendering DOM compiled.

Comment: By reading the manual however you can find all the answers. 
`you can pass the data object as the second parameter to template in order to render immediately instead of returning a template function.`

Comment: @AdonSmith: `t = _.template(x)` gives you a function in `t`, then you `h = t(o)` to get HTML in `h`, or you can `h = _.template(x, o)` to go straight to HTML without saving the intermediate function. Use the first form when you want to use the template more than once and the second form for one-offs.